Start an app from layered jar directories?
I have a spring-boot app that supports layered jars.
My maven-generated big jar MyApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is divided into directories
application
dependencies
snapshot-dependencies
spring-boot-loader

But I do not want to use it with a docker-image - all I found about layered jars was with its usage in a docker-image.
I want to have the split but not for an image.
So how can I start my app with these 4 dirs existing and not building docker layers first??

Can you explain why you want to run with the jar contents split into separate dirs? When running a built Docker image, the content is not actually split up into separate directories, but is combined back into a single dir in the resulting image.

I do not want a docker-image. I have a big jar where the most of its size never changes (dependencies). I want to split it up so I only need to update the small amount of classes and keep depencendies on the server.

I understand you don't want a Docker image. I was curious why you'd want the files split out without layering in an image. Spring Boot doesn't have anything to help you if you want to explode the jar file and put things in different directories, you'll need to set up the classpath yourself when you run java on the extracted content.

I tried to unpack the fat-jar and then pack it again. As far I see its content is exactly the same - but I can not lauch it.
